# Error : Spinner cannot be cast to EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know what's the problem with this layout :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/seticonimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/cm7_icon" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/vsname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seticonimage"
    android:hint="@string/entername"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/vsdesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vsname"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seticonimage"
    android:hint="@string/shrtdesc"
    android:inputType="text" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vsdesc"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seticonimage"
    android:prompt="@string/icon_prompt" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spinnerinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/seticonimage" />
```

But it closes with this error :

```
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Spinner cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.manager.boot.free.MultiBootManager.onContextItemSelected(MultiBootManager.java:144)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2509)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3521)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:924)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-06 06:01:18.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1979):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.editvslayout,
                null);
        final EditText evsname = (EditText) textEntryView
                .findViewById(R.id.vsname);
        final EditText evsdesc = (EditText) textEntryView
                .findViewById(R.id.vsdesc);
        final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) textEntryView
                .findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final ImageView i = (ImageView) textEntryView
                .findViewById(R.id.seticonimage);
```

Comment: Seems you are inflating a spinner into an EditText object. Showing your Java code will be helpful.

Comment: please also provide the code and the part of the error msg which contains the references to YOUR own code - this will provide you (in most cases) with the line of the error - as Chromium says, that's most likeley...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its seems that you have did code like:

```
Spinner mSpinner = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.spinner);
```

Instead, it should be casted properly as:

```
Spinner mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById (R.id.spinner);
```

Comment: Oh come on man.....Its time wasting task here. You should have posted earlier. :(

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem?

Comment: what i can say now, just clean your project. @PareshMayani is absolutely right

Answer (score 5):

Please clean your project because it may be possible that you had assign an id to `Spinner`, `R.java` builds, but later you assign the same name to `EditText` without building `R.java`.

As R.java keeps reference of all controls, so at first time you assign to spinner so `R.java` consider that this id is a spinner but now you assigned it to EditText and R.java is totally unaware until you clean and build .

moral: sometimes you have to build `R.java` manually

Comment: I even tried restarting eclipse, anyway I just reverted to an old working layout, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then goto **Project** -> **Clean** hopefully that will resolve the issue. It did resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio / IntelliJ 15 I often have to 'Build/Clean Project' a few times. When that doesn't work (which is fairly often), I end up deleting the Build directory. Then it works. I can't offer a reason why, but I'd love one from IntelliJ. In my case IntelliJ is mixing up the values for view IDs.